# Why if I have to set the pthread_sigmask before I wait to the specific signal

Tags: c, signals

In one of threads I have to wait for specific real-time signal, but I don't understand why first I have to set the whole sigmask for thread before waiting for specific signal.

```
    sigset_t signals;
    siginfo_t info;

    sigfillset(&signals); 
    sigdelset(&signals, SIGRTMIN+1);

        //why do we need this?
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &signals, NULL);

    sigemptyset(&signals);
    sigaddset(&signals, SIGRTMIN+1);
    sigwaitinfo(&signals, &info);
    printf("This is thread %d %d\n", pthread_self(), info.si_value.sival_int);
```

Comment: The other signals shouldn't need to be masked. It's just a choice. But I'm not sure if the `sigdelset(&signals, SIGRTMIN+1);` is a good idea. The spec for http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html says it's UB to call it if the argument set isn't blocked. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwaitinfo.html doesn't appear to have such a clause and I don't know why it's needed for `sigwait`, but I think keeping keeping `SIGRTMIN+1` blocked wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking to code it seems that developer want to suspend execution of thread until `SIGRTMIN+1` has become pending for thread([sigwaitinfo(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html)). At the same time he don't want thread execution should be disturb by other signals(i.e. thread should not react to any signal except `SIGRTMIN+1`) so he masked other signals using below statement:

```
//why do we need this?
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &signals, NULL);
```

The point to note here is even though all signals are masked except `SIGRTMIN+1` using above statement, thread execution is always prone to `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL.`